What is the title of this sex comedy from (I think) the 80s?
I saw it in 1985. I can't remember if it was an American movie or dubbed in English. It was about an outcast trying to get laid through wacky schemes. I remember two scenes:
He dresses up in a nightgown and sits in a circle with some girls, pretending to be one of them. While they talk, he gets an erection that he keeps pushing down. They notice and freak out. I think this is the part where an angry mob catches him and dresses him like a weirdo in the village square.
In the other scene he tries to make Spanish Fly in a lab, but someone replaces it with fart pills. He goes on a date with a classy looking lady, slips her some pills and she farts so badly in his vehicle (which in my memory is a semi) that he puts on a gas mask. Eventually she puts a cigarette in her mouth, and after failing to stop her from lighting her lighter, the truck explodes.

I Googled "movie farting pills" and found the 1984 film "The Party Animal". Here is the scene in the car you're talking about. From IMDb:

Pondo Sinatra is a college boy with a problem: women will have nothing to do with him. It's not that he was raised on a chicken farm and, literally, came to school on the back of a turnip truck. It's not that he is a virgin and jinxed, and every move he makes around a woman backfires. The problem is that god and heaven have set themselves against Pondo losing his virginity. That is until Pondo discovers the secret formula to the most powerful aphrodisiac in the world and becomes....... "The Party Animal"!


I thought it would be funny, but no :(

Yeah, that scene didn't look like it came from a very good movie...!

Just piling on here, but I think it's a stretch to call that 'comedy'. :)
